# Is my HTACCESS causing too many mysql connections?

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

if anyone can help I would be VERY grateful.

We have a CMS running 3 websites (international versions on separate domains) on the same hosting package which had been happily running for over a year without any problems until the other when we made some changes to the .htaccess file in order to make the URLs "prettier".

The structure of the site is:

```
-pages
   -home.php  <-- UK (www.site.com)
      -your-basket.php  <-- SSL (UK only)
      -your-account.php  <-- SSL (UK only)
      -page.php
         -sub pages etc

   -de
      -home.php  <-- German (www.site.de)
         -page.php
            -sub pages etc

   -it
      -home.php  <-- Italian (www.site.it)
         -page.php
            -sub pages etc
```

Everything starts at /pages/ and follows down the structure with the exception of /pages/posts/ which contains the news posts for all sites (there is not a /pages/de/posts/ for example) - posts are tied to a news page through a page ID in the DB.

The purpose of the .htaccess was to remove /pages/ from the URL altogether and make each site look like a standalone site rather than showing the de/it subdirectories in the url (eg. www.site.de/page.php rather than www.site.de/de/page.php) but is this correct or are there any glaring errors which might be causing loops or anything:

```
RewriteEngine On

ErrorDocument 404 /
ErrorDocument 500 /

#compress text
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml application/xhtml+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript application/javascript text/javascript text/css
FileETag none

<ifModule mod_php5.c>
 php_value zlib.output_compression 16386
</ifModule>

#use cache
<FilesMatch ".(ico|pdf|flv|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|js|css|swf)$">
        ExpiresActive On
        ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 year"
</FilesMatch>


### SSL specific redirects
#need to be placed before any other rewrites

# force https for basket and account pages
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =off
RewriteRule ^(pages/your-basket|pages/your-account)\.php$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

# don't do anything for images/css/js (leave protocol as is)
RewriteRule \.(gif|jpe?g|png|css|js)$ - [NC,L]

# force http for all other URLs
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(pages/your-basket|pages/your-account)\.php$
RewriteRule .* http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]



### Canonical redirect of home page
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /index\.php\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(.*)index\.php$ /$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /home-page\.php\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(.*)home-page\.php$ /$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /home\.php\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(.*)home\.php$ /$1 [R=301,L]


#set home pages - add home.php for international sites
DirectoryIndex index.php home.php


#### IT ####

# Redirect /it/ Requests - if subdir is present this removes it
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET.*/it/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^localhost(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?[^/]+/(.*)$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Map http://www.site.it to /subdir.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.site.it$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^site.it$
RewriteRule ^$ /pages/it/ [L]

# Map http://www.site.it/x to /subdir/x unless there is a x in the web root.
# If url does not contain "posts" execute to subdirectory
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.site.it$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^site.it$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !^GET.*/posts/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/pages/it/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /pages/it/$1

# Map http://www.site.it/x to /subdir/x unless there is a x in the web root.
# If url does contain "posts" rewrite to root
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.site.it$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^site.it$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET.*/posts/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/pages/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /pages/$1


#### DE ####

# Redirect /de/ Requests - if subdir is present this removes it
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET.*/de/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^localhost(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?[^/]+/(.*)$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Map http://www.site.de to /subdir.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.site.de$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^site.de$
RewriteRule ^$ /pages/de/ [L]

# Map http://www.site.de/x to /subdir/x unless there is a x in the web root.
# If url does not contain "posts" execute to subdirectory
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.site.de$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^site.de$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !^GET.*/posts/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/pages/de/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /pages/de/$1

# Map http://www.site.de/x to /subdir/x unless there is a x in the web root.
# If url does contain "posts" rewrite to root
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.site.de$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^site.de$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET.*/posts/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/pages/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /pages/$1


#### UK ####

# Map http://www.site.com to /subdir.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.site.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^site.com$
RewriteRule ^$ /pages/ [L]

# Map http://www.site.com/x to /subdir/x unless there is a x in the web root.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.site.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^site.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/pages/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /pages/$1
```

If I haven't explained it well enough please let me know. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Are you getting an error or something? What's your question exactly?

Comment: Sorry, yes, we keep getting an error saying the site is hitting "max_user_connections" in mysql and the usage seems to have increased a lot but the number of visitors hasn't so it indicates something looping or calling the same thing a number of times per request. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any directives using a database connection. So there is no obvious cause for the additional connections and the mysql error message.

However, it might cause the connections to stay open for longer, if it slows down the whole system. I tested your rules on my system with Apache Bench (ab) and a simple `GET` request. For 10000 requests the wall clock time went up from ~4.2 sec to ~9.9 seconds.

I would definitely look into PHP as well and verify that there haven't been changes as well. If not, you can look into using a database connection pool, if you haven't already.

Since you already have everything in separate directories, you could also move uk to its own subdirectory and setup virtual hosts with the `DocumentRoot` set to the appropriate subdirectory. Then you can put specific htaccess files in each document root. This eliminates the tests for `%{HTTP_HOST}` and cuts the size to roughly one third of the original size.

Additionally, you can move the directives to the virtual host context. This reduces the load further, because then Apache must read and parse the directives only once and not for every request.

Comment: Thank you very much for taking a look at this and for such a detailed response. I haven't looked into database pools yet but will investigate that option.

Comment: What you have said about separating the UK into its own directory also makes sense so I may try that initially. As long as the htaccess directives look ok in priniciple and are not creating any obvious loops or could be more efficient, that is good news. Thanks for all your advice and your prompt response.

Comment: just a thought - given the site structure as it is (as I've detailed above) and ignoring the current htaccess we have, what directives would you recommend to do what we need? ie. so each site displays www.site.com/page.php and www.site.de/page.php rather than www.site.de/de/page.php or www.site.de/pages/de/page.php? Although the rules we're using (above) work, they have been taken from a number of sources and I'm not sure they are the best way of achieving what we need...

Comment: @washoc If you can setup virtual hosts with the document root at the `uk`, `de`, `it` directory, you don't need rewrite rules at all. Then you should be able to just use `/page.php` out of the box. You must only deal with the http/https switch, and the posts directory. Although, it might also depend on the web application/framework you're using.